# Intercept small circular delete button in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to modify my table view cell apparence when the delete button came in. When it appear after swipeing i can intercept it with this method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

the problem is that this method is not called when I'm in edit mode and i press on the small circular delete button that causes the appearance of the delete rectangular button.

Anyone can explain me how to intercept it? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `setEditing:animated:` in the cell subclass. Make sure to call `super`'s `setEditing:animated` as well.

Comment: Ok, but how I can know when the circular button is tapped?